# How to install Zend Framework through PEAR using WAMPSERVER2.2 (64-bit)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pear

As the title states, I am having considerable problems in installing the Zend Framework through PEAR. After spending most of the day on this I'm quite surprised and frustrated with the lack of documentation, so as a result I was hoping the community would help me out.

Today I decided to change from XAMPP to WAMPSERVER2.2 for my development environment. After configuring the environment correctly and attempted to install Zend, I was dismayed to find that it does not come with the PEAR manager by default (that raises the question, why the hell not???). As a result I had to go download `go-pear.phar` and run the install under the command prompt `>php go-pear.phar`. All seems to run quite well... however, after adding the Zend channel `zend.googlecode.com/svn` trying to install the package via `pear install zend/zend` I run into problems, i.e. No releases available for package "zend.googlecode.com/svn/zend" install failed.

Tearing my hair out over this... could it be that pear was installed incorrectly? Why after adding the channel would the install fail? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where pear is supported by ZF http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/introduction.installation.html, For the easiest install grab the newest Zend Server Community Edition, it comes with ZF and will set the paths in windows.

Comment: Here is the official ZEND channel in PEAR http://code.google.com/p/zend/  Cant get it working with WAMPSERVER.. .although XAMPP works fine. Looks like I'll just have to do the install the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting upset about the wrong things. I hope I can give you a few clarifications.

1. PEAR installer and the WAMP (Windows Apache MySQL PHP) stack of your choice are not connected in any way and it is good, if such packages let you handle your own PEAR environment independently from it.
2. The time of XAMPP and WAMPSERVER are over, use Zend Server Community Edition, it's so much better, more stable, easier to set up, easier to configure.
3. Zend Framework is just a library, it doesn't need any installation. Why don't you just download it, place it wherever you like and put it on your PHP include path?
4. The installation over PEAR as you describe it, works for me, maybe you don't have the latest PEAR manager. Find out which PEAR version you have installed with `pear list`.

The most important point is. You only need to learn about the PHP include path and you can solve this problem in no time in any environment independently of any W/L AMP stack or PEAR installation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. True. PEAR has just been the way I've always obtained the Zend package and it was just frustrating not being able to get it working in the newer environment. I have since done away with PEAR and gone with the "easy" way of downloaded the Zend Framework from the website, unpacking and setting my include path. I've been meaning to have a look at ZSCE and will do so when I have a chance.

Comment: upgrading is so much easier when you installed it via pear.

Comment: @cweiske Do you only ever develop one project? And if not, do all your project always use the same version of ZF?

Comment: @markus-tharkun: you can do per-project installs with PEAR and Pyrus.

Comment: @cweiske cool, I missed that and started using composer instead. do you have a link to instructions on how to do that?

Comment: pyrus: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.differences.frompear.php#pyrus.differences.frompear.configuration
PEAR: use `pear config-create /path/to/pear/ pear.conf` and then `pear -c /path/to/pear/pear.conf install $package`

Comment: Also about pyrus: http://saltybeagle.com/2011/01/using-pyrus-to-manage-pear-installable-vendor-libs/

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late, but in case someone else runs into the same problem, this may help:
http://code.google.com/p/zend/issues/detail?id=25

It's basically a problem with pear and cache.